# Notification does not show on lock screen on Xiomi devices

Tags: android, firebase, react-native, firebase-cloud-messaging, android-notifications

I'm using [push notifications by zo0r](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-push-notification). Notifications are working fine but neither they show up on lockscreen nor they wake up mobile even though i've set priority to high and visibility to public. any solution?

```
 visibility: 'public',
 priority: 'high',
 importance: Importance.HIGH,
```

Answer (score 0):

While sending the notification U can set priority to high.

Look at https://docs.expo.dev/versions/latest/sdk/notifications/

Also [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Scdk2.png)

May It gonna be work.

Comment: dude read question completely. priority is already set high. plus i'm using cli not expo

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).